# SublimeText3: How to set spaces to 4 on .py file only?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am using SublimeText3 and writing HTML/CSS so I set spaces to 2 on editing HTML/CSS files but I want to use 4 spaces **auto** on editing .py files.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have any particular file open, choosing `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` will open/create a set of preferences that apply only to files of that particular type.

Settings in a syntax specific preferences file are applied ***on top*** of the global default preferences, allowing you to specify for particular files that you would like a few things to be configured differently, while all other settings remain at the global preference.

So generally speaking, to have different settings for Python, do this while you're editing a Python file and apply settings to the right hand pane that apply the specific settings changes you would like to see in Python files.